# How many strings of eight English letters are there that contain at least one vowel, if letters can be repeated?

Tags: combinatorics

The answer is can be easily calculated as $26^8 - 21^8$.
But to my understanding, an alternative solution could be and I think should be ${8\choose 1} \times 5 \times 26^7$
But these two are not equal. I think I'm counting something extra in the case of the second one. Can anyone please provide some insight like what I am doing wrong?

Comment: In the second method, you could first  place the vowel $A$ in the first slot and then you place $E$ in the second slot as part of the $26^7$ or you could first place the vowel $E$ in the second slot and then you place $A$ in the first slot as part of the $26^7$.  Your method would count those as two separate arrangements, though they coincide.  Should stress: your second method yields a value greater than $26^8$...that is, greater than the total number of $8$ letter strings.

Comment: More broadly:  if your combination has exactly $k$ vowels, then your second method counts it $k$ times, according to which vowel is designated as the special choice.

Comment: "you could first place the vowel $A$ in the first slot and then you place $E$ in the second slot as part of the $26^7$ or you could first place the vowel $E$ in the second slot and then you place $A$ in the first slot" - I don't quite understand how the second method regards them as different? could you please explain?

Comment: What could be a fix for it?

Comment: Your second method says: "pick a slot from the $8$.  Choose a vowel to put in that slot.  Then populate the remaining $7$ slots however you like."  Thus if you pick slot $1$ and insert an $A$ there, then happen to put an $E$ in slot $2$, that is different from picking slot $2$ first, inserting an $E$ there, and then happening to put an $A$ in slot $1$.

Comment: If you want to fix it:  for each $k$ from $1$ to $8$ let $S_k$ be the number of eight letter strings with exactly $k$ vowels.  Then your answer is the sum of the $S_k$ and you can use something akin to your second method to compute $S_k$.

Comment: To understand why the second method over counts, work a simpler case by hand.  Consider strings of length two instead of length eight.  Now persuade yourself that your method counts each two vowel string twice.

Comment: The method you mentioned is done in the answer below. I have the sense now how $A$ in the first slot and $E$ in the second slot (as part of $26^7$) and $A$ in the first slot (as part of $26^7$) and $E$ in the second slot (as part of having at least one vowel) are different. But still, I couldn't see/feel it concretely. The case you mentioned 
-strings of 2 letters - to work out still has 235-260 different strings - difficult to work it all out by hand.

Comment: I was wondering how one might've known that a string of k vowel is being counted k times in the second method. Eg If there wasn't any forum like this, how would/should a young mathematics student have worked it out himself? It seemed very reasonable when I thought of it, that flaw didn't come to my mind at all. How did you work it out or how do you usually think while tackling problems like this? If there's any book or resources, could you please mention it?

Comment: Then simplify further: two vowels A and E, three consonants B,C and D. Only 25 options total.

Comment: As you remark, this is a very common error...very easy trap to fall into.  I always suggest people work out small examples.  That's an essential habit anyway, and it really clarifies this issues.

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given answer is the straightfward one: all strings of length $8$ minus all strings of length $8$ that have no vowels. It seems intuitive and obviously correct.

Your alternative answer selects a position for a vowel ($\binom{8}{1}$ ways), then there are $5$ vowels to put in that chosen place and then all other characters are allowed for the remaining $7$ places hence the $26^7$ (with $21^7$ we would count all words with *exactly* one vowel, more later on that)

But that counts at least double *all* strings that have 2 or more vowels!

For example AABBBBCC can be made in two ways: when we pick position 1 for the vowel and when we pick position 2. So your alternative counts that string twice. And with a string three vowels thrice, etc.

More generally let $C_k$ be the number with *exactly* $k$ vowels.

Then that number can be counted analogously (without doubles) as

$$C_k = \binom{8}{k}5^k 21^{8-k}$$

(note that we force non-vowels outside of the $k$ vowel positions).

So the asked for number is

$$\sum_{k=1}^8 C_k = \sum_{k=1}^8 \binom{8}{k} 5^k 21^{8-k}$$

and as the binomial expansion tells us

$$26^8 = (5+21)^8 = \sum_{k=0}^8 \binom{8}{k}5^k 21^{n-k}$$ subtracting these gives us reconfirmation that the correct answer is

$$26^8 - 21^8$$

Comment: `@Henno Brandsma if you could also provide your insight in the comment above....